# photo album on iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

The below code is for go to photo albums.The below code shows an error. I'm adding the UIImagePickerControllerDelegates like this in my .h file:

```
@interface My_Pictures : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegates>
```

But I'm not importing anything in my .m file. Should I include any of the Frameworks? Please give me a clear explanation.

```
ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ipc.delegate = self;

if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}
else {
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement delegate like this in .h class

```
@interface My_Pictures : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum().

Comment: My_Pictures is my class name..Error:class 'My_Pictures' does not implement the 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate' protocol..

Comment: You have this Method : - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo

Comment: You have this: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo

Comment: i'm not having...if i want to add that method means please explain for what purpose should i want to add that method...

Comment: please tel me the purpose of this method: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo

Comment: Images are correctly saved to photo album usingUIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()..